# Why doesn’t node.js get the exact content of my file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've started experimenting with node.js because I'm interested in the back-end part of JavaScript. Now, I want to extract the content of a file and check whether it's equal to (what I think) is the content of the file. I've made sure to not have any spaces in my file.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("datei.txt", "utf-8",function(err, f){
    
    if(f == "hey!"){
        console.log("worked!");
    }else{
        console.log("didn't work");
    }
});
```

[image: That's the content of my file]

Comment: Might not be the issue but it's `UTF8` not `UTF-8`. There might also be line-breaks that you're missing...

Comment: Have you tried printing `err`? Have you tried printing `f`?

Comment: @tkausl: err = null. also, f gives me the exact content of my file *but* there is an empty line under it. any idea why?

Comment: Probably because there is a newline in your file.

Comment: No. that's why I said that there isn't a space after "hey!"

Comment: @Andy `'utf-8'` is an alias for `'utf8'`.

Comment: please `trim()` the strings and compare to see if the issue is whitespace, or encoding

Comment: trim() worked! thank you so much @ITgoldman. Do you want to make it a proposal to get those yummi karma points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may trim() the strings and compare to see if the issue is whitespace, or encoding. My guess it's whitespace :-) Possibly Unix vs Windows new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a new line in the datei.txt. Add trim to compare:

```
if (f.trim() == "hey!") {
```

I have tested and worked for me.